# How to use javascript to focus (get the cursor on it) on an HTML <input type="text"> tag

Tags: javascript, html, focus

Let's say there's I have the following code: -

```html
    <div onclick="document.getElementById('inputfieldxyz').focus"> CLICK ME TO FOCUS ON THE INPUT TAG </div>

    <input id="inputfieldxyz" placeholder="This becomes ::focus 'ed when the div above is clicked">
```

So... Yeah... How do I click and the ***div*** and make the ***input*** tag show up the cursor like the way it does when the input tag is clicked?

P.S.: I can't use jQuery. Is there a way to do it using plain javascript? (Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need to add `()` to `.focus` so it's `.focus()`

Comment: *I can't use jQuery* - then please don't tag as [jquery] (tag removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.focus()` not `.focus`.

```html
<div onclick="document.getElementById('inputfieldxyz').focus()"> CLICK ME TO FOCUS ON THE INPUT TAG </div>

    <input id="inputfieldxyz" placeholder="This becomes ::focus 'ed when the div above is clicked">
```

Alternatively, HTML5 also supprts the `autofocus` attribute :

```
<input type="text" autofocus />
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a `div` with additional javascript, instead use a `<label for=id>` as this is exactly what they're for:

```html
<label for='inputfieldxyz'> CLICK ME TO FOCUS ON THE INPUT TAG </label>
<input id="inputfieldxyz" placeholder="This becomes ::focus 'ed when the div above is clicked">
```

Comment: That's a long workaround... Instead of that I had to change the .focus to .focus() and it really helped! Thanks anyway!